# jQuery UI resize while keeping same overall width

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, resize

I have two containers laid out horizontally via `position: absolute`. I'm trying to make a "resize bar" in the middle such that dragging it will increase one element's size while decreasing the other (hence keeping the overall width the same).

```
<div class="container left"></div>
<div id="resizeBar"></div>
<div class="container right"></div>
```

[image]

Then I initialize them like this:

```
function initUI () {
    $('.container').resizable({handles: 'e,w'});
    $('#resizeBar').draggable({axis: 'x'});
}
```

I'd like the left container's E handle and the right container's W handle to "follow" the resize bar when I drag it. Does jQuery UI have a built-in mechanism to do this? If not, what's the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first consider some CSS to make think easier where you will only need to adjust the `width` of one element and the other one will follow:

Here is a simplified example considering the `mousemove` event:

```js
$('#resizeBar,.container').on('mousemove',function(e) {
  $('.left').width(e.pageX - 20);
})
```

```css
body {
  display:flex;
  height:200px;
  color:#fff;
}
body > .container.right {
  background:#000;
  flex:1;
}
body > .container.left {
  background:#000;
  width:50%;
} 
#resizeBar {
  width:10px;
  background:red;
  margin:0 5px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container left">left</div>
<div id="resizeBar"></div>
<div class="container right">right</div>
```

Comment: may i ask you to take a look at a jQuery draggable and droppable related question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54498364/jquery-drag-and-drop-simulation-does-not-work-for-the-last-draggable ?