# how to achieve the column resizing?

Tags: html, css

It means when I drag one border of div, the rest divs will automatically adjust themself. Just like the example of jsfiddle. when you drag the right border of html panel, the css panel will adjust themselves according to that. Are there any simple ways to achieve it?

[image]

Comment: I think [split.js](https://nathancahill.github.io/Split.js/) is what you're looking for - or HTML framesets :P

Comment: I found similar topic - I think it will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960193/how-to-make-html-element-resizable-using-pure-javascript

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50722853/jquery-ui-resize-while-keeping-same-overall-width/50723221#50723221